# Simple CMD script giving error

Tags: windows, cmd

Newbie to scripting so please be nice.

Running the query via CMD works fine, when i try to create a batch file its giving errors.

```
@echo off
cd c:\test123 && for /r %F in (*) do if %~zF LSS 30000000 del "%F"
```

Runs fine in CMD but following error occurs when trying to run it from a batch file

> "LSS was unexpected at this time."

Bascially trying to CD to a directory to run a command to remove any files under 30mb

Comment: double the percent sign. When trying to find the reason for such problems it often a good idea to leave out the `@echo off` because then you can see what happened to what you wrote.

Comment: Just had a read. Thanks really clears things up.

Comment: @achandab A hint: Next time you use a Windows standard command not knowing the syntax, open a command prompt window, run the command with `/?` as parameter and read the output help. Try it out with `for /?` and `cd /?` and `del /?`.

Comment: cheers for that Mofi. Will do :)

Answer (score 1):

for use in batchfile, you have to double the percent-signs of your `for` variable:
 `for /r %%F ... do ...if %%~zF ... del "%%F"`

You should also add the `/d` parameter to `cd` to be able to switch to another drive letter.

Comment: Cheers that worked perfect. Sorry for the noob questions. Still learning!